# Using ARC'ss Authorization editor

Tags: advanced-rest-client

I'm using the advanced REST client and wan't to create a request with a Java Web Token.
Hence i used the authorization editor and selected "Bearer" and inserted my token into the respective field.

I assumed that the Authorisation Editor automacially generates the header for the autorization, but the request doesn't seem to work (I got a role error depending on the missing authentication).

When i type the Authorization header manually, it works.

So how can i use the Authorization Editor to automatically insert the information to the header?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the application. There was a bug in version 16 regarding this issue. This upcoming release (currently in beta) has this fixed.

Comment: Very cool, i'm looking forward.
Thank you!